# "key cannot be null" when parsing xaml in a datagrid text column

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid and it has a text column in it, configured this way:

```
  <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static ResViewModel:SC.Resources.HelloWorld}" />
```

Here `ResViewModel` is the `xmlns:namespace`, `SC` is the project namespace, `Resources` is the resource file name and `HelloWorld` is a string property.

But I try to parse this xaml, I get an error like

> Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key...

Can you help me to understand why is this error occuring? Also what is the best way to access resource file without using the `LocBAML` tool?

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues:

1. "SC is the project namespace" - that should go into the xmlns definition.
2. You can't access files with this syntax, unless you have a dependency object with the same name.

There's a good approach to retrieving strings that is described [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/10/30/wpf-localization-on-the-fly-language-selection.aspx). It's focusing on Localisation, but it will work for a single language as well. This approach has it's downsides, but it's the lesser evil than other routes.